# Spring Tools Suite shows plenty of errors in all projects out of nowhere

Tags: java, eclipse

Today i'm launching Spring Tools Suite and all my project show errors. Majority of them are "x cannot be resolved to a type". I can ignore them and launch program and it works, but i suppose such things shouldn't happen. I have copy of them, but i want to know what is the source of the issue and how to fix it if it's possible.

The only things i have changed lately in STS was installing Window Builder and Maven, but i doubt any of it should make problems. Actually only 2 projects don't show errors - both use Maven and one uses Window Builder.

Comment: Try a Project->Clean...->Clean all projects. This happens a bunch with Eclipse. If that fails, right-click your project->Maven->Update Project..., Select All and hit OK.

Comment: Zero reaction. I don't want to update projects with maven because not all of them use it.

Comment: Did you recently apply a Java update? Are all of the entries on your **Installed** **JREs** preference page still valid?

Comment: I have updated java. But i haven't changed anything about these projects. I have never checked any preferences so it's hard to say is it valid. Edit It says "JRE System Library [jre1.8.0_201] (unbound). I have plenty of projects so i would prefer fixing them all at once instead of one by one (if they can be fixed at all).